# How to get javascript to Select new element that has just been created?

Tags: javascript, object, element, queryselector

I am making a book list, and it has a delete button on it. The creating element up untill appendChild is working already, the problem is just the delete button.

The code for books:

```
function createEach(e){
  let divTitle = document.createElement('div');
  divTitle.className = 'cell medium-3';
  divTitle.innerHTML = Book.title;
  divTitleNd = divTitle.outerHTML;
```

The code for delete button:

```
let deleteBtn = document.createElement('a');
  deleteBtn.className = 'del-btn button tiny alert';
  deleteBtn.innerHTML = 'x';
  deleteBtn.href = '#';
  deleteBtnNd = deleteBtn.outerHTML;
```

before i have document.querySelector the delete button with the class del-btn, but now if i run this code:

```
let deleteButton = document.querySelector('.del-btn');
function deleteBook(e){
  e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

the delete Button for newly created element just wont work. Any way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need `deleteButton` if you already have `deleteBtn` ?

Comment: the deleteButton is for selecting the ones in HTMl. deleteBtn is the new one i created

Comment: Seems like a lot is missing here. Maybe a brief working example would be helpful where everything necessary is present.